# ¿por qué mi página html no enlaza con la imagen del icono de la página?

Tags: html, imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]En home.html si enlaza la página

en mi directorio la carpeta principal de proyecto se llama alexandrawp dentro hay una carpeta que se llama paginas principales donde tengo 18 paginas que quiero enlazar a la imagen del icono y dentro tambien copie alex.ico, y junto a esa carpeta hay otra que se llama imágenes donde esta alex.ico
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esque no enlaza con ninguna de las 18 páginas que estan dentro de la carpeta paginas principales, ¿cómo debería ser mi ruta? y ¿si está bien las etiquetas que utilizo para enlazar la imagen?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo que esta en home

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="imagenes/alex.ico">
```

Este es mi codigo que está en la pagina captura de pantalla

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="alex.ico">
```

en otras paginas tengo así, pero tampoco funciona

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../imagenes/alex.ico">
```

Comment: Alexandra, bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Quiero que sepas que en esta comunidad [un fragmento de código vale más que mil imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2990/29967). Por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/131532/edit) cambiando las imágenes con código por el código real, o sea, por el texto en sí. De ese modo se podrá examinar mejor y eventualmente usar para pruebas si fuera necesario. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posible solución:

1-Dado que tus fotos estan en carpetas al mismo nivel que las paginas, deberias llamar asi:

```
href="../imagenes/alex.ico"
```

2.La otra opcion podria ser, ya que copiaste la imagen en la misma carpeta de las paginas

```
href="alex.ico"
```

Comment: no sale,¿hay otra forma de inserta el icono?

Comment: ya lo solucioné estaba cambiando el favicon, cuando lo que queria cambiar era el logotipo

Comment: @LuisFernando ¿Cómo se diferencia esto de lo que ya está expuesto en la pregunta?

Comment: @AlexandraLoor ¿A qué te refieres con "_estaba cambiando el favicon, cuando lo que queria cambiar era el logotipo_"?

Comment: la imagen pequeña que aparece en la pestaña al lado del titulo de la página

Comment: @AlexandraLoor entonces, ¿quieres cambiar el favicon o el logo de la página? Porque no son lo mismo y no está quedando claro con las explicaciones.

Comment: queria cambiar el logotipo pero ya lo solucioné